# Как получить обратную ссылку на файл?

Tags: php, файлы

Код обработчика:

```
$uploaddir = "temp";
if (copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "temp/" . $_FILES["filename"]["name"]))
{
    echo("Файл успешно загружен");
    echo ("Ваш файл успешно загружен <a href='" . $uploaddir . basename($_FILES ['file']['name']) . "'>here</a>.");
}
else
{
    echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
}
```

Почему-то по нажатию на ссылку меня просто перенаправляет в директорию с файлом, а мне нужно, чтобы появлялось окно загрузки файла.

Также выдаётся уведомление:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in z:\home\zakach.ru\www\upload.php on line 100

Для этой строки:

```
echo("Ваш файл успешно загружен <a href='" . $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) . "'>here</a>.");
```

Comment: `$_FILES["filename"]["name"]` != `$_FILES ['file']['name']`

Comment: Вместо `copy` используйте `move_uploaded_file` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: А как сделать чтобы меня не перенаправляло в каталог? А выводило окно загрузки?

Comment: Если файл у вас есть на месте куда ссылка указывает, то будет окно для его скачивания. Если нет, то извините, нечего скачивать.

Comment: У меня просто открывает этот файл в браузере (если в chrome) а если в opera то всё норм,... Как можно сделать так чтобы везде начиналась закачка?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

**Решение для сервера под управлением Apache**

Чтобы файлы загружались на компьютер, а не открывались в браузере разместите в нужном каталоге сервера файл `.htaccess` с таким текстом

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</IfModule>
```

P.S. У вас это каталог temp в который файлы сохраняются.

Comment: Вроде `application/octet-stream` лишний?

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно конечно и без него, но почему не указать, что мы отдаем на скачивание двоичный файл?

Comment: Тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download можно глянуть вопрос/ответ.

Comment: На мой взгляд, нехорошо передавать неправильный mime-тип. Любого из этих заголовков хватит, чтобы файл скачался. Вариант с content-disposition хороший, вариант с изменение mime-типа мне не нравится. А использовать их одновременно я вообще смысла не вижу.

Comment: По твоей же ссылке принятый ответ: "No.

The content-type should be whatever it is known to be, if you know it."

Comment: @Qwertiy, значит удалю эту команду. Хотя на работоспособность она не влияет ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, но главное во всех примерах по инету всегда прописывают две эти команды вместе :) Пример http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root

Comment: Тогда я хочу знать почему. Т. е. где конкретно одна из них не работает и какая?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я бы тоже хотел это знать, но поиск в гугле ни чего толкового не дал. Кроме того, что в IE 5.5 SP1 были проблемы с заголовком `Content-Disposition attachment` :)

Comment: А эти проблемы как-то выживают в IE Quirks 5, или касаются только настоящего 5.5?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Обработчик должен в **первую очередь** проверять `$_FILES["filename"]["error"]`

И если эта переменная не равна нулю, то выводить сообщение об ошибке параллельно записывать код ошибки в лог файл.
Расшифровку кодов можно смотреть здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php