# html ссылка при клике показывалось окно сохранить как / куда

Tags: html

```
<a href="img/hello.jpg">скачать</a>
```

Как сделать ссылку, при нажатии на которую перед скачкой браузер покажет окно, куда сохранить файл, вместо загрузки по умолчанию в директорию загрузок браузера (если это вообще возможно)?

Comment: На этот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444824/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/444842#444842 ответ посмотрите.

Comment: спасибо, но что бы файлы сохранялись по урлу, достаточно сделать так <a href="img/hello.jpg" download="">скачать</a>

Comment: Судя по этой информации http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp работает пока не везде.

Comment: не знаю почему у вас метод из моего сообщения не работает, но на локальном компе создал папку, кинул туда .htaccess с правилом и проверил откртие jpeg файла из папки на FF 40 и IE 11. Оба браузера выводят окошко, где спрашивают, что с файлом делать.

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать так:

```
<a href="img/hello.jpg" download="hello.jpg">Download</a>
```

"сохранить как" вызвать не получиться, потому что все браузеры по умолчанию качают в папку Download, изменить  на "сохранить как" нужно в браузере пользователю вручную в настройках браузера.

Comment: погодите, а на стороне клиента а не сервера это можно как-то сделать? :)

Comment: Вроде узнал, только таким заголовком от сервера можно окно "сохранить как" вызвать header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');

Comment: исправил, проверьте так